# How to call promise function recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I am trying to call an asynchronous function recursively using javascript promises but haven't found a pattern that works.

This is what I imagine would work:

```
var doAsyncThing = function(lastId){
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    // async request with lastId
    return resolve(response)
  }
}

var recursivelyDoAsyncThing = function(lastId){
  doAsyncThing(lastId).then(function(response){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      //do something with response
      if(response.hasMore){
        //get newlastId
        return resolve(recursivelyDoAsyncThing(newLastId));
      }else{
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}

recursivelyDoAsyncThing().then( function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

Why doesn't this work? What have I misunderstood?

Is there a better pattern to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recursivelyDoAsyncThing` needs to return a Promise in order to continue the chain. In your case, all you need to do is have `doAsyncThing` return its Promise:

```
var doAsyncThing = function(lastId){
  // Notice the return here:
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
```

Then add `return` to your `doAsyncThing` call like so:

```
var recursivelyDoAsyncThing = function(lastId){
  // Notice the return here:
  return doAsyncThing(lastId).then(function(response){
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `return` in the `recursivelyDoAsyncThing` function. Also you should [avoid the `Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572):

```
function recursivelyDoAsyncThing(lastId) {
  return doAsyncThing(lastId).then(function(response) {
//^^^^^^
    //do something with response
    if (response.hasMore) {
      //get newlastId
      return recursivelyDoAsyncThing(newLastId);
    } else {
      return; // undefined? Always return a useful value
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple example of recursive promise. The example is based on calculation `factorial` of number.

```js
let code = (function(){
 let getFactorial = n =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   if(n<=1){
    resolve(1);
   }
   resolve(
    getFactorial(n-1).then(fact => {
     return fact * n;
    })
   )
  });
 }
 return {
  factorial: function(number){
   getFactorial(number).then(
    response => console.log(response)
   )
  }
 }
})();
code.factorial(5);
code.factorial(6);
code.factorial(7);
```

Comment: perfect example as most of the developer started recursion with factorial.

Comment: Good example. Thanks